# Python pdf to txt

Tags: python-2.7

I would like to convert pdf file to txt. Here is my code:

```
testFile = urllib.URLopener()
testFile.retrieve("http://url_to_download" , "/Users/gabor_dev/Desktop/pdf_tst/tst.pdf")

content = ""

pdf = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(file("/Users/gabor_dev/Desktop/pdf_tst/tst.pdf", "rb"))

for i in range(0, pdf.getNumPages()):
    f = open("/Users/gabor_dev/Desktop/pdf_tst/xxx.txt",'a')
    content= pdf.getPage(i).extractText() + "\n"
    c=content.split()
    for a in c:
        f.write(" ")
        f.write(a)
        f.write('\n')
        f.close()
```

My pdf is downloaded, but when I try to convert it to my txt only the first word of the pdf shows up in my txt file, and then I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gabor_dev/PycharmProjects/text_class_tst/textClass.py", line 26, in <module>
    f.write(" ")
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: Well, you close the file after having written the first word using `f.close()`. If you only close the file at the very end, your code should be able to write the rest of the data...

Comment: ohh, thank you! :) my code indent wasn't good.. thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Better use `with open` :

```
import urllib
import pyPdf

testFile = urllib.URLopener()
testFile.retrieve("http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf" , "./tst.pdf")

content = ""

pdf = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(file("./tst.pdf", "rb"))


with open("./xxx.txt",'a') as f :
    for i in range(0, pdf.getNumPages()):
        content= pdf.getPage(i).extractText() + "\n"
        c=content.split()
        for a in c:
            f.write(" ")
            f.write(a)
            f.write('\n')
```

Tested and works